# browsersync with wamp external access

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver, browser-sync

Browsersync seems great and I have it running well on my test machine and syncing across browsers. However, I can't get external devices (eg phone) to work with it.

I can connect to my localhost from my phone using my IP address (192.168.0.4) but I can't get it to connect to the port suggested by browsersync (192.168.0.4:3000) thus I don't get the live reload features. It returns a timeout error.

I'm using WAMP for my Apache/PHP and can't help but think it's a setting in Apache I've got wrong.

BrowserSync Settings:

```
browserSync: {
        dev: {
            bsFiles: {
                src : [
                    'js/main.min.js',
                    'css/style.css',
                    'images/**',
                    '*.php'
                ]
            },
            options: {
                watchTask: true,
                proxy: 'localhost:80',
                host: '192.168.0.4',
                //logLevel: 'debug'
            }
        }
    },
```

Apache Settings:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride All

 Order Deny,Allow
 Allow from 127.0.0.1
 Allow from localhost
 Allow from 192.168.0.4 # Local machine
 Allow from 192.168.0.3 # Samsung Galaxy S4
```

I have also tried on my work machine without success (although it too has similar settings).

Any thoughts on what I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is having a similar issue - it turns out it was because my work network was set as a 'public' network not a 'work' or 'private' network. At home, connecting to a VPN was causing the issue. So a couple of things you can check - Firewall, Network settings and VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone else or future me. BrowserSync will grab the IP from the first network adapter it finds. In my case this was an adapter from old Vagrant box. Check adapter setup with ifconfig / ipconfig. You can specify the correct IP using the 'host' directive in the BrowserSync task.

Ex:

```
gulp.task('serve', function(){
    browserSync.init({
        proxy   : "http://local.site.com",
        host    : '192.168.1.195'
    });
});
```